# Larger edit area for SMS writing?

Tags: sms, text-editor, text-input, handcent-sms

The Handcent app has a feature where with a click of a button I can switch to a larger edit area. This allowed me to preview my messages in whole before sending them off and edit them comfortably.

Now I've had to uninstall Handcent due to space issues (old Nexus One, very low memory for apps), and this is the only feature I miss in the stock messaging app. Is there a way I can enable this feature in the stock Messaging, or is there some small app that does this in a natural way without interfering with other functionality?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be *rooting* the device, to obtain the "Mms.apk", and manually reverse-engineering it (using tools like [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)), and finding the overlay that's showing the text edit area's size (and the step that naturally follows, increasing it :) )